# Problem with executing a function on saving a post

Tags: plugins, actions, save-post

Here is my basic plugin code. I am just starting from scratch. I will explain the functionality. It is simple, While my plugin is active it will add a new meta box in add new post page just below the tags box. The user can add a value to my text box & i will save that value with post ID to my table. You can understand what is happening after reading my code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Post Extender
Author: Jithesh Kt
Version: 1.0
*/

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'extra_meta_form' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_extra_meta' );
function extra_meta_form() {
    //global $theme_name;
    add_meta_box( 'post-meta-boxes', __('Extra Fileds'), 'extra_meta_form_view', 'post', 'side', 'default' );
}

function extra_meta_form_view()
{ ?>
<table class="form-table">
<p>Extra Meta filed :  <input type="text" id="custom_input" name="custom_input"/></p>
</table>
<?php }

function save_extra_meta($post_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."extra_post_meta";
    $query_result = $wpdb->insert($tablename, array('post_id'=>$post_id,
    'filed_name'=>"My Text",
    'value'=>$_POST['custom_input']
    ));

}
?>
```

Now after activating my plugin I clicked on Add New 
Added a post title, Content & my a value in newly added text box.

The result i am expecting in my table is :

[image: Expected]

But actually this what i got in my fresh table :(

[image: Result]

How did the data got duplicated ?
From where did the other data came ?

This is driving me crazy. Running behind this rabbit since last two days. I tried many methods. Same result. Data is always duplicating & unknown data insertion too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action `save_post` is also called during AJAX auto-save requests. But your value is not sent then, so you save an empty value for something that isn't set.

Start your save function with:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
```

See basic examples with more checks [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87478/how-do-i-position-meta-box-on-post-edit-screen/87516#87516) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77316/how-to-make-shortcode-to-hide-selection-of-text-from-post-or-page/77323#77323).

Comment: Thanks. I did as u said. Modified my save function little bit :

function save_extra_meta($post_id)
{
 if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
 if(isset($_POST['custom_input']))
 {
  global $wpdb;
  $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."extra_post_meta";
  $query_result = $wpdb->insert($tablename, array('post_id'=>$post_id,
  'filed_name'=>"My Text",
  'value'=>$_POST['custom_input']
  ));
 return;
 }
}

Now data duplication stopped. Still the function is running two times and creating two rows of data :(

Comment: You should use the regular post_meta table and `update_post_meta()`.

Comment: Mate i am dealing with wpdb. I have log way to go and need to make lot of database stuff. :)

Comment: Then you should check first if there is already a value for this post ID. And please escape `$_POST['custom_input']` before you send it to the database.

Comment: Checking post id is waste of time i think. Because in database u can see post id is always getting some values. See this function. This also inserting values two times with fake/not existing post id :

http://pastebin.com/FBfsmZFu

Answer (score 0):

When you reload your admin page the wordpress fires the 'save_post' action through AJAX and send metaboxes values blank. Resulting the blank fields. You can retain your fields value by

```
    add_action('save_post', 'custom_function');

    function custom_function($postid) {
        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $postid;
        }
        // Your functionality
    }
```

Comment: Any reason to copy my answer? :)

Comment: The code i have written is pretty simpler than yours and give a clear idea where to add these AUSTOSAVES

Comment: Look at my code & result :(

http://pastebin.com/FBfsmZFu

http://i.imgur.com/HRpqDLs.jpg

Comment: Look @jitesh every time you run wp_insert. The problem with your code is each time you save your post, an entry is been inserted in your table. Try to use update if key exists rather than inserting.
Every time your data get saved as a seperate entry because when you reload the admin page it fires a AJAX Request to your save post action and inserting record on every update.