# Add metabox without the container

Tags: metabox

I want to add a second input identical in design/functionality to the Title text input, directly beneath it.

I can use

```
add_meta_box('catchy_title', 'Short Title', array('catchyTitle', 'metaBoxShow'), 'post', 'normal', 'high');
```

And the content

```
<div id="titlewrap">
     <label for="catchy_title" class="">Enter shorter title here</label>
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="catchy_title" value="'.$meta.'" size="20" name="catchy_title">
 </div>
```

However this puts a grey metabox around it. Should I even be using a metabox? I basically want to duplicate this field:

[image: title]

but I end up with

[image: wrong]

and it's under the rich text editor too.

Here is the full code if it helps: http://pastebin.com/NiFHAUmq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the action `edit_form_after_title`.

Example:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', function() {
    echo 'Enter some text: <input type=text>';
});
```

[image]

See [this answer for another example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/87516/73).