# Render content after post title in wp-admin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I want a plugin to place custom content below the post title, and to the right of the permalink. However, I cannot find a specific action reference to hook into. The screenshot demonstrates the location idea.

How this would be done in pre-3.5 Wordpress ? Is there a specific action reference?

[image: Location of rendered content]

Comment: I'm just curious, what kind of page builder to you have installed there?

Comment: This is [carrington build](http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/carrington-build/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add something on the same line, but right after the permalink box is an action: `edit_form_after_title`.

See [How do I position meta_box on post edit screen after the title?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87478/how-do-i-position-meta-box-on-post-edit-screen) for an example.

Also, you don’t even know if there is enough room for a second box on the permalink line. There are other plugins extending the width of that box to full width.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running Wordpress 3.4.1. Is there another, now possibly more hacky way to trigger it?

Comment: Update immediately.

Comment: I am sadly restrained in my ability to do so. I will inject some content into a hidden div, then use javascript to position it correctly. Even though I hate doing this!

Comment: You really need to try to sell that update to whoever has the power to do it. 3.4.1 is pretty old.